# Problem using formula

Tags: formula, checkbox, admin

I want to create a formula checkbox that indicates if the Month of Date_Offered__c is equal to the current month. For ex :- If Date_Offered__c = 5 May 2021 Then checkbox will be checked And if Date_Offered__c = 5 June 2021 then, checkbox will be unchecked.
Date_Offered__c is a Date type field.
I tried using this formula, but am getting an error:

```
MONTH(DATEVALUE( Date_Offered__c )) = MONTH(DATEVALUE( TODAY() ))
```

Comment: What if the date is 5 May 2020?

Answer (score 0):

[DATEVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5) function used in DateTime Field, `Date_Offered__c` is Date Type Field So, Try Below Formula.

```
MONTH(Date_Offered__c ) = MONTH( TODAY())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the month AND year are the same as today:

```
MONTH(Date_Offered__c ) = MONTH( TODAY())
&&
YEAR(Date_Offered__c ) = YEAR( TODAY())
```